# Django allauth: Multiple user registration with email-only authentication causing UNIQUE constraint error

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-users, django-auth-models

I have an issue with a django allauth project

I typed that in settings.py to disable username field and use email address

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET= True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True
```

when I register for the first time it successfull, but when i tries to register another user raised me error : UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

[error with seccond register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JL5f.png)

I expect that happend because unique not effected to field

Comment: In Django Framework, the username is [required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username), so AllAuth automatically provide something for the username. It takes the first part before the @ of the email as username if I remember correctly.

Comment: Have you used a custom user model? The configuration you used seems to be for a [custom user model](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models)